# Counter variable for array index inside XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xsl stylesheet as follows:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html">
    </xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="record">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h3>{$attr}</h3>
      <table border="1">
          <tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="cd">
            <td style="text-align:left"><a href="http://localhost:8010/disp1.xqy?varName={$y[i]}"> <xsl:value-of select="value" /></a></td> 
            </xsl:for-each></tr> 
       </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

$y is a string array holding values "123" and "456" in positions $y[1] and $y[2] respectively. I want a solution so that i can increment the value of i in $y[i] so that in each iteration of for-each select="cd" , it passes the coorect value to the varName in href tag. Can anyone please help me on how to do this? The xml document through which the xslt traverses is as follows :

```
<cd>
<value>123</value>
</cd>
<cd>
<value>456</value>
</cd>
</record>
```

I am new to xslt.So can anyone please try to help me on this?

Comment: I don't see that `$y` is defined anywhere in your stylesheet (or `$attr`, for that matter). Do you even need it? What is your expected output in this example?

Comment: Along with an XSLT stylesheet that shows how you define `$attr` and `$y`, exactly, please also include a syntactically correct sample of the XML input and the actual HTML you would want to get from it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your stylesheet is not full as variables **attr** and **y** are not declared anywhere. I also assume that **y** is a node set rather than array, as array parameters are not supported in XSLT.

If the value of **i** is linked to the index of **cd**, you can use function **position()**.

`<td style="text-align:left"><a href="http://localhost:8010/disp1.xqy?varName={$y[position()]}"> <xsl:value-of select="value" /></a></td>`

Also, if your **varName** values correspond to the values of **value** elements in the source, why do you need an array to hold the same values?

`<td style="text-align:left"><a href="http://localhost:8010/disp1.xqy?varName={value}"> <xsl:value-of select="value" /></a></td>`